# Algorithm for a robot to explore and map an unknown space

Tags: algorithm, robotics

I'm working on making a pathfinding entity, which I'll refer to as the robot. The programming language doesn't matter to me.

The robot uses Dijkstra's algorithm to pathfind and move through an enclosed area. However, in order to pathfind, the robot needs to have a map of the nodes in an area. To get this map, the robot will need to move around the area, recording obstacles and walls.

The area will look something like this.

[image]

In order to check whether a node is valid to move to, the robot has to be next to it—it doesn't have any longer range sensors. It has to physically move around to check nodes, too.

I've looked at Depth-first searching, which, as I understand it, explores branches of nodes one at a time. However, it has to keep back-tracking to check other branches. This would be very slow for a physical robot.

**What is the best way for a robot to map an area by moving around? What are some solutions or existing algorithms to this problem?**

Comment: Research for Shakey the robot solved some of these problems. For example, if you can measure the distance from every corner to its immediate two neighbouring corners and put the results in an adjacency matrix, you can run the Floyd-Warshall algorithm on the matrix and get the shortest distance between all pairs of corners - very useful for path planning with Dijkstra's. However if there are nodes in the middle of the room, you'll likely have to scan up and down since you have no ranged detection.